# Bar graph not within axis

Tags: d3.js, graph

I'm having trouble having the bar graph contained within the axis. I tried adjusting the margin but it's still below the x-axis. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thankyou

this is my margin:

```
margin = {
    top: 70,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 70
},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
padding = 15;
```

[image: Bar graph]

Comment: @Robert Andersson Thank you for your quick response. if I'm understanding you correctly. I should replace this code:  `var y_domain = d3.extent(NestbyDate, function(d) { return d.values; `    For thi                                                    
` var y_domain = d3.max(NestbyDate, function(d) {
            return d.values.length;`  Right? Sorry if for my lack of knowledge question.

Comment: Rober Andersson's solution: But you need to adjust your y_domain variable so that it calculates the max value in your dataset, again because you're nesting the data it would look like this: `var y_domain = d3.max(NestbyDate, function(d) { return d.values.length; });` and in your `y.domain()` you set `y.domain([0, y_domain])` – @Robert Andersson                 Thank you very much Robert. I learn a lot from you today.

Comment: No problem! If you solved it you can delete the question, otherwise please post *all* the code as either a snippet here on stackoverflow or on plunker/jsfiddle (for example) so we can help you more easily.